# How to dynamically lookup an EJB at runtime

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.1

I have this scenario where i have my EJB3 beans in a jar file, deployed successfully to Jboss EAP-6.4.

Then I have another web project that looks up these EJB's inside a REST POJO class. I can currently access the EJB's from inside the web project using `@Inject` and `@EJB`, but my use case is one that i don't know which beans i need to load until runtime and the list is not static, so i might need to lookup 10 EJB's or none for a particular request etc.

I know I can possibly use

```
InitialContext.lookup('ejb:/.....')
```

to retrieve my EJB beans from inside the web project, but is there a way that i can retrieve them without that round trip(i believe), or maybe what am just looking for is a more elegant way to do EJB look-up at runtime just like the statically typed `@EJB` and `@Inject` versions.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

In my REST POJO classes i don't want to hard code any @Inject or @EJB annotations, rather i want that when a request comes in i look-up(for lack of better word) the EJB's that will handle the request, so all the decision is made at runtime really, as shown below

```
@Path("/path")
public class TestService {

    @GET("/{id}")
    public String loadGetPath(@Param id int id){
        //at this point i want to dynamically resolve the EJB based on 
        //the value of id
    }
}
```

Comment: Just let the "unknown" EJBs implement a common interface and inject that instead?

Comment: @BalusC, thanks for the answer however i already do that. And that doesn't solve the primary issue i have which is, i want to do the lookup dynamically and at runtime, also it is the concrete bean implementation i want to look up dynamically at runtime not the interface which is empty really.

Comment: Then I don't understand your concrete problem with that. Injecting an interface should work just fine if there's a suitable implementation provided.

Comment: @BalusC, ok maybe i didn't really understand. But this is what am explaining. I have an interface that has hundreds of beans implementing and using it as their remote interface. If i "@Inject MyInterface" this remote interface into my REST POJO, my question would then be, how do i tell it to load bean-1 and not bean-2 and remember at runtime, which is the primary issue that i have to solve.

Comment: `@EJB(lookup="...")`?

Comment: @BalusC, this works. However i want that line to be dynamic, as in i don't know which bean(s) i need at the time of implementation, only at runtime. so i want that when the request comes in i load 20 beans or 10 beans or 0 beans as the case maybe and execute the method that is generally implemented.

Comment: I posted an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500655/replace-hardcoded-class-implementations/35542109#35542109) that should sort you out

Comment: @kolossus, thanks a lot i think this is what am looking for. Especially the bean manager part. I will try it and see the outcome. You should have answered the question directly so that i can mark it as answered.

Comment: No wahala :). The answer was originally meant for that question; yours just happens to be in the same direction as the OP of the other. Ordinarily, I should mark this one as a duplicate, but I can't because the OP of the other question hasn't accepted the answer there yet. You're welcome to upvote it however, if the answer helps you @NnamdiJibunoh

Answer (score 0):

Whoopdicity blog: [Developing a dynamic JEE service client with CDI](http://whoopdicity.blogspot.com/2014/07/developing-dynamic-jee-service-client.html)  seems to have what you are looking for. At the end it claims you can do:

```
public class MyServiceConsumer {

    @Inject @ServiceClient
    private MyBusinessService service;

    ... 
}
```

Instead of

```
public class MyServiceConsumer {

    @EJB(lookup="...")
    private MyBusinessService service;

    ... 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response however am not sure the explanation meets my needs. I have also edited the question to add a small code sample maybe that will make my initial question more readable.